# Maven home (M2_HOME) not being picked up by IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: macos, maven, intellij-idea, osx-lion

I am trying to do a simple maven build with IntelliJ IDEA 10.5.1 on OS X Lion and am getting the following error:

> Error running my-app [package]: No valid Maven installation found.
>   Either set the home directory in the configuration dialog or set the
>   M2_HOME environment variable on your system.

I have set M2_HOME to the following, but I am still having issues.  And yes, I did restart IntelliJ.

```
$ echo $M2_HOME
/usr/share/maven
```

I then manually entered the path to maven in IntelliJ's Maven Settings for the project.  This is not something that I want to do for every project, so is there something I am missing with how to get IntelliJ know where my maven home is?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Mac OS apps cannot read bash environment variables. Look at this question [Setting environment variables in OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x) to expose `M2_HOME` to all applications including IntelliJ. You do need to restart after doing this.

Comment: Worked like a charm.  I'm a noob to OS X, so thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: See also [JetBrains recommendations](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-1160) for solving this.

Comment: @Jonik that link is dead, so now I may never know official recommendation for how to fix this ;-)

Answer (score 35):

type in Terminal:

```
$ mvn --version
```

then get following result:

```
Apache Maven 3.0.5 (r01de14724cdef164cd33c7c8c2fe155faf9602da; 2013-02-19 16:51:28+0300)
Maven home: /opt/local/share/java/maven3
Java version: 1.6.0_65, vendor: Apple Inc.
Java home: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: ru_RU, platform encoding: MacCyrillic
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.9.4", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

here in second line we have:

```
Maven home: /opt/local/share/java/maven3
```

type this path into field on configuration dialog. That's all to fix!

Comment: This worked. Thanks a lot. There were 2 dots after the bin folder in the command line and the moment I added the exact path in IntelliJ, it picked up and the error was gone

Answer (score 11):

Another option is to add the M2_HOME variable at: `IntelliJ IDEA=>Preferences=>IDE Settings=>Path Variables`

After a restart of IntelliJ, `IntelliJ IDEA=>Preferences=>Project Settings=>Maven=>Maven home directory` should be set to your M2_HOME variable.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. `Maven home directory` field is still empty.

Answer (score 7):

Got to this answer ? probably the answers above are to long ...

just type in :

```
echo "setenv M2_HOME $M2_HOME" | sudo tee -a /etc/launchd.conf
```

and restart your mac (thats it!)

restarting is annoying ?  just use the command :

```
grep -E "^setenv" /etc/launchd.conf | xargs -t -L 1 launchctl
```

and restart IntelliJ IDEA

Answer (score 7):

If `M2_HOME` is configured to point to the Maven home directory then:

1. Go to `File -> Settings`
2. Search for `Maven`
3. Select `Runner`
4. Insert in the field `VM Options` the following string:

   ```
   Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=$M2_HOME
   ```

Click `Apply` and `OK`

Answer (score 3):

In case you don't want to use the M2_HOME and want to direct the IntelliJ to the maven installation you can simply set it by:

- goto **File => Setting => Maven => Maven home directory**
- point to your maven build directory e.g. /usr/local/maven/apache-maven-3.0.4

A better way is to have a symlink e.g. 'latest' for the latest version and point your IntelliJ to use that for consistency, given latest points to the latest version of maven installed on your box.

Answer (score 3):

If you are having this problem with a homebrew installation of maven 3 on the OSX 10.9.4 then check out this [blog post](http://digitalsanctum.com/2010/12/31/maven-3-homebrew-install/).