# M2_HOME not found in IntelliJ IDEA 11 on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: java, macos, maven, intellij-idea

I am trying to get IntelliJ to understand where the path variable M2_HOME is, obviously I am failing. I have added it in the .bashrc but after what I read from other posts this on sets the variable in the CLI. Where should I add it, and so it is set each time I login?

I have read the other StackOverflow posts about the topic but I don't understand where I should add it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To set it you can either edit your `~/.MacOSX/environment.plist` to add your env variables (such as M2_HOME)

Here is mine :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>M2_HOME</key>
    <string>/usr/local/Cellar/maven/2.2.1/libexec</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Or you can set it manually in IntelliJ's configuration:
[image: IntelliJ configuration panel]

---

**Related issues:**

- [Setting environment variables in OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x)
- [Maven home (M2_HOME) not being picked up by IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053666/maven-home-m2-home-not-being-picked-up-by-intellij-idea)

**Resources:**

- [developer.apple.com - Setting environment variables for user processes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1067/_index.html)

Comment: Ok, so the plist file is working? And also, does all enviroment variables that you need in GUI apps go here?

Comment: Exactly, but you'll have to reboot (re-login actually) to access these env vars.

Comment: Sorry for asking dumb, but this means that these shells does not have the same location of where they find enviroment variables?

Comment: I don't really get what you mean.

Comment: In other words, why doesn't it work when I add them in .bashrc/.bash_profile etc

Comment: You .bash_profile is executed when you start a new shell, but when you start a new application there is no need to start a shell. So .bash_profile isn't executed.

Comment: Ok, so that file is another place to add such env. variables. Thank you for your help, it is now working :)