# How to remove Modules from a Intellij Maven Project permanently?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, dependency-management

I am currently working on a larger scale Maven-based project in IntelliJIdea 12.1.6 Ultimate. I have been working with IntelliJIdea since about 5 months.

An included module has dependencies on another module. The dependent module's source was also part of my project until recently. Since I removed the dependent module from my project, I get compile errors whenever I am trying to compile the source without maven.

The pom.xml of removed modules in Intellij seem to be placed onto the Settings->Maven->Ignored Files. I cant seem to remove it from there, only check or uncheck it. It's not possible to include the module again since IntelliJ will say its still under Ignored Files.

2 ways allow me to compile again: Uncheck the pom from Ignored files, which will include the module again in my project. Or delete the source of the dependent module, so my project will load the dependent module from the maven repository. But whenever I update my project from svn, the source of the dependent module is restored (I don't know why this even happens since its not part my project) and the cycle begins anew.

I googled this for a while since it gets really annoying. It became a problem with several excluded modules. I could rebuild the intellij-project from scratch but since a lot of IntelliJ settings were made (not related to the problem) I would rather solve this.

Any help is appreciated, I guess I must be missing something

Answer (score 47, accepted):

A collegue who has more in-depth knowledge of maven told me the answer:

The trick is not to remove the source module from the intellij project but to remove it from maven (in the maven projects tab in intellij). Intellij will ask then to remove the source module also from the intellij project and its finally gone.

Right click on the maven project -> remove projects

Would not have guessed this makes such a difference.

Comment: sometimes, `remove projects` is disabled. Right click your project > open module settings, delete your module. Then, delete the module contents on disk.

Answer (score 2):

Do any of these two points work for you:

- **NEW** there might be dependency in one of your sub-modules pointing to the removed artifact. To make sure it's the situation, you may want to rename your $HOME/.m2 and rebuild the project. If this is indeed the case, just search for the dependency in your poms and delete it from sub-modules
- right click on the parent `pom.xml` -> Maven -> Reimport
- copy the project into a separate dir. File -> Import Project -> Choose newly created dir -> Choose Maven?

PS. Idea is excellent in maintaining the project structure in accordance with Maven project. Once you make a change to your pom, you need to reload the project. Idea can also automatically detect changes made to your `pom.xml` and apply them to project. To enable this, press <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+A</kbd>, type 'maven auto', choose "Importing", checkbox "Import Maven project automatically";

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Reimport did not work. When i try to import the project again like you proposed, intellij says "nothing found to import", i am not quite sure about the location of the project file for intellij that contains the information about all modules which are currently part of the project. Your tip with auto importing was helpful, since it prevents the need for clicking the green popup when poms are changed. I guess the problem is that maven or intellij still thinks of the excluded module as part of the project and tries to use compilate from there, instead of the repos

Comment: To import a project with Idea, you need to point to the dir containing the top-level `pom.xml`. I have one more guess, updating the answer...

Comment: i tried copying the project to a seperate dir and reimporting it. it still throws the same compiler error "symbol not found" because it cant find the dependent module. for your new suggestion, i changed m2_home in intellij like proposed in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053666/maven-home-m2-home-not-being-picked-up-by-intellij-idea. sadly it had no effect. i tried also renaming my local mvn repos which forced all dependencies to be loaded again from our artifactory. i want to clarify project structure in next post

Comment: This means that you have these dependencies somewhere else in the project and this is the reason they are fetched from your artifactory repo. These can be transitive or explicitly declared. `mvn dependency:analyze` will check this. `mvn dependency:tree` will show the complete dep tree. Make sure you don't have your dependencies there.

Comment: There are currently 5 modules in my project. They are dependend on a number of self made libs/modules and several external ones, which is all clearly stated in the pom.xml of each module. A module that was imported in and removed from intellij, and to which one of my active modules is dependend, is not found by intellij, and intellij seems to be confused and does not seem to try to get it from local or remote mvn repository. I get a compilation error when i compile anything in intellij (any runnable class), but not when i build with maven. There are no dependency collions by maven.

Comment: Have you tried 'File -> Invalidate Caches' and deleting '$HOME/.IntelliJIdea12/system' if it doesn't help?

Comment: source of module a in my project is dependend on module b which is also part of my project right now, module b is dependend on the excluded module c. the compilated classes of module c are existent in my local and my remote repository. intellij should fetch module c from somewhere, and not search in my project where i already excluded the source. i will try to invalidate the caches, but i dont think this will solve it since it is a persistent problem. my original problem is that intellij does not properly exclude/remove the source of module c (i think :)).

Comment: invalidating the caches brought no different result. thank you for your effort anyhow, i learned a lot. maybe i will need to rebuild the intellijproject from scratch after all. i am still wondering why the source modules are not excluded completely

Answer (score 2):

This may not relate directly to the OP, but...

Using **IntelliJ 2016.5**, to remove a Maven module *and* it's underlying source code *and* remove it as a sub-module from the parent, go to the `Project Files` tab, find the unwanted module and use the triangle symbol to open it, *then* delete the entry that represents it on disk.

Hitting `Delete` on the module itself will only mark it as hidden within the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone encounters a similar problem in recent times, the following steps worked for me:

1. Right-click on the project/module that you want to remove.
2. Select "Maven" from the context menu.
3. Choose "Unlink Maven Projects" from the dropdown list.
4. Finally, select "Remove" to delete the project/module.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still experiencing this. This is what worked for me:

1. Rigth click on the module to remove.
2. Select "Remove Module" fro the context menu.
3. Right click on the same module again. This time you should see an option "delete" in the context menu.
4. Click on "delete" and the module is gone.

Hope this helps