# Setup Maven for IntelliJ 13

Tags: java, macos, maven, intellij-idea, maven-2

Maven was installed and was working just fine before with my previous versions of IntelliJ Idea.

I just installed the trial version on IntelliJ 13 and my existing maven project stopped working!

The error was:

```
No valid Maven installation found.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution was to set the `Maven Home Directory` manually in your to your executable mvm location [/usr/local/maven] in my case.

Other solutions I came across needs a reboot.

Alternative solution here:

1. [M2_HOME not being picked by IntelliJ Idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053666/maven-home-m2-home-not-being-picked-up-by-intellij-idea?rq=1)
2. [Setting environment variable in OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x)