# Has IntelliJ IDEA downloaded the Maven automatically?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

My question is a little different from [Setup Maven for IntelliJ 13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20486881/setup-maven-for-intellij-13).

My **IntelliJ IDEA** version is 14.0.3, and I didn't download any **Maven** in my computer before. I can create **Maven** project well, but the maven home directory is empty:
[image]

and the **Maven** menu doesn't contain **clean, compile, package ...**,
[image]

If the IntelliJ IDEA has built-in Maven, where is the Maven?

So, it seems that IntelliJ IDEA hasn't downloaded the **Maven** itself and I should download it and set the **M2_HOME** manually, right ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to download and install a Maven distribution manually. As far as I know, IntelliJ doesn't do it automatically. As for the "Maven home directory" field, my preference is to explicitly choose the directory where Maven was installed, rather than setting a global "M2_HOME" environment variable.

Comment: Since there is any **Maven** now, why can I create a `Maven project` and it can download the decencies properly? How does IntelliJ enable that ?

Comment: Simply because you have the Maven IDEA plugin enabled. If, however, M2_HOME is not pointing to a valid Maven installation (and there is no directory explicitly chosen), then any attempt to execute a goal will fail.