# SonarQube Local Script in IntelliJ can't find mvn (IOException/No such directory)

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, sonarqube

My maven build works fine in IntelliJ IDEA. That is not the issue. The issue is relating to SonarQube Community Plugin.

```
ERROR 17:08:38.358 > java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mvn" (in directory "/Users/chrismanning/Projects/Registry/registry/idea-files"): error=2, No such file or directory
```

Local analysis script:

```
mvn sonar:sonar 
-DskipTests=true 
-Dsonar.analysis.mode=issues
-Dsonar.scm.enabled=false 
-Dsonar.scm-stats.enabled=false 
-Dissueassignplugin.enabled=false 
-Dsonar.preview.excludePlugins=emailnotifications,issueassign 
-Dsonar.report.export.path=sonar-report.json
```

I definitely have maven installed and in my path. (it's symlinked in /usr/local/bin)

```
chrismanning@Chriss-MacBook-Pro:~/Projects/Registry/registry/idea-files$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.2.5 (12a6b3acb947671f09b81f49094c53f426d8cea1; 2014-12-14T12:29:23-05:00)
Maven home: /Users/chrismanning/apache-maven-3.2.5
Java version: 1.8.0_40, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.10.3", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

M2_HOME and PATH are propely defined in /etc/launchd.conf

Comment: Sorry, but this might be a possible duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053666/maven-home-m2-home-not-being-picked-up-by-intellij-idea

Comment: Followed solution for that and moved my M2_HOME declaration and PATH additions to that file. (then restarted IntelliJ)

No luck here

Comment: Also tried restarting PC per that answer's directions just in case. Still no luck

Comment: @hooknc That was actually the problem, but that stackoverflow link did not provide the proper solution. That method of setting environmental variables is outdated for Mac OS X Yosemite.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**If you're using Yosemite (like I am) you must set environmental variables this way**

1. Create new file at ~/Library/LaunchAgents/environment.plist
2. Add this code block and modify to appropriately set your environmental variables

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
   <plist version="1.0">
   <dict>
     <key>Label</key>
     <string>my.startup</string>
     <key>ProgramArguments</key>
     <array>
       <string>sh</string>
       <string>-c</string>
       <string>
       launchctl setenv JAVA_HOME /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home
       launchctl setenv M2_HOME /Users/chrismanning/apache-maven-3.2.5
       </string>        
     </array>
     <key>RunAtLoad</key>
     <true/>
   </dict>
   </plist>
   ```
3. Save and restart your computer. This is the proper way to load Yosemite environmental variables

**If you are using an older version of Mac OS X, see this answer**

[Setting environment variables in OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x)

Comment: Good job on finding the answer yourself.  Don't forget to select your answer as the right answer.

Comment: Does this work for terminal as well? Or, do I have to add `export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/..."` in some where else too (like, `/etc/profile` or `~/.bash_profile`)?

Comment: Should work fine in terminal. Just make sure to restart your computer after adding the launch agent file. However if you're running El Capitan I think the way to set the variables changed. I haven't upgraded my Mac yet but a coworker was having problems with this on El Capitan.

Comment: Be sure to use the *RAW Paste Data* from that pastebin snippet (the formatted version is borked).

Comment: Ah, I'll have him try that. Thanks Perry.